# Connecting two queries to get Cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
SELECT 
d.GUID, w.word
FROM
dictionary d
    JOIN
word w ON w.ID = d.ID_word
WHERE
w.id_language = #ID#;
```

if `#ID# = 1` it returns table

```
GUID | word
-----------
1    | A
2    | B
3    | C1
3    | C2
4    | D1
4    | D2
5    | E
```

if `#ID# = 2` it returns table

```
GUID | word
-----------
1    | AA
2    | BB1
2    | BB2
3    | CC
4    | DD1
4    | DD2
6    | FF
```

Now I want merge these two tables/queries to get a table which looks like that:

```
GUID | word1 | word2
--------------------
1    | A     | AA
2    | B     | BB1
2    | B     | BB2
3    | C1    | CC
3    | C1    | CC
4    | D1    | DD1
4    | D1    | DD2
4    | D2    | DD1
4    | D2    | DD2
```

So basically it is a table of the Cartesian product of the rows with the same GUID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need subqueries:

```
SELECT d1.GUID, w1.word, w2.word
FROM dictionary d1 JOIN
     word w1
     ON w1.ID = d1.ID_word JOIN
     dictionary d2
     ON d2.GUID = d.GUID JOIN
     word w2
     ON w2.id = d2.ID_word
WHERE w1.id_language = ? AND
      w2.id_language = ?;
```

I think this is more readable using CTEs:

```
WITH dw AS (
      SELECT d.GUID, w.word, w.id_language
      FROM dictionary d JOIN
         word w
         ON w.ID = d.ID_word
     )
SELECT dw1.GUID, dw1.word, dw2.word
FROM dw dw1 JOIN
     dw dw2
     ON dw1.GUID = dw2.GUID
WHERE dw1.id_language = ? AND
      dw2.id_language = ?;
```

In both these examples (and what is implied by your question) GUIDs with only one word are filtered out.  These can be included by tweaking the queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from 
 (  -- if #ID# = 1 it returns table
    SELECT 
    d.GUID, w.word
    FROM
    dictionary d
        JOIN
    word w ON w.ID = d.ID_word
    WHERE
    w.id_language = 1
 ) as t1
join
 (  -- if #ID# = 2 it returns table
    SELECT 
    d.GUID, w.word
    FROM
    dictionary d
        JOIN
    word w ON w.ID = d.ID_word
    WHERE
    w.id_language = 2
 ) as t2
-- Cartesian product of the rows with the same GUID
on t1.guid = t2.guid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just `JOIN` your two queries on `GUID`:

```
SELECT q1.GUID, q1.word AS word1, q2.word AS word2
FROM (
    SELECT 
    d.GUID, w.word
    FROM
    dictionary d
        JOIN
    word w ON w.ID = d.ID_word
    WHERE
    w.id_language = 1
) q1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
    d.GUID, w.word
    FROM
    dictionary d
        JOIN
    word w ON w.ID = d.ID_word
    WHERE
    w.id_language = 1
) q2 ON q2.GUID = q1.GUID
```